# Dropdown default value

Tags: php, joomla

Hi my dropdown getting value from below code:

```
 public function getFloorsHTML() {
     $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
     $db = JFactory::getDbo();
     $query = $db->getQuery(true);
     $myflrs = $jinput->get ('fvalue');
     $query->select($db->quoteName(array('id', 'f_name')));
     $query->from($db->quoteName('#__pk_flrs'));
     $query->where($db->quoteName('bldg')." = ".$db->quote($myflrs));
     $db->setQuery($query);
     $results = $db->loadObjectList();
     foreach ($results as $result) 
     {
       echo '<option value="' . $result->id . '" > ' . $result->f_name.'</option>'; 
      }
    exit; 
}
```

Code is working fine but how can i have "Please Select" as default value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the option before the results.

```
echo '<option value="">Please Select</option>';
foreach ($results as $result) 
{
   echo '<option value="' . $result->id . '" > ' . $result->floor_name.'</option>'; 
}
```

Comment: If there is no `option` with `selected` attribute, the first `option` will be selected by default. @u_mulder

Answer (score 0):

Put selected=selected in the form.

`<option selected="selected" value="">Content</option>`